# Black background in circular image view in Lollipop

Tags: background, imageview, android-5.0-lollipop

I have used Circular Image View to implement profile image in circular shape with some colored border. The code works perfect on pre-lollipop devices.

But, the same code **on Lollipop** device shows a **Black Background** behind the rounded image view.

Tried many guesses but unable to fix the bug! Please help.

Below is the code :-

```
public class CircularImageView extends ImageView {
private int borderWidth = 4;
private int viewWidth;
private int viewHeight;
private Bitmap image;
private Paint paint;
private Paint paintBorder;
private BitmapShader shader;

public CircularImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setup();
}

public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setup();
}

public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setup();
}

private void setup() {
    // init paint
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    paintBorder = new Paint();
    setBorderColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rounded_imageview_border));
    paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);
    this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);
}

public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
    this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    this.invalidate();
}

public void setBorderColor(int borderColor) {
    if (paintBorder != null)
        paintBorder.setColor(borderColor);

    this.invalidate();
}

private void loadBitmap() {
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) this.getDrawable();

    if (bitmapDrawable != null)
        image = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
}

@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // load the bitmap
    loadBitmap();

    // init shader
    if (image != null) {
        shader = new BitmapShader(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image,
                canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), false),
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        int circleCenter = viewWidth / 2;

        // circleCenter is the x or y of the view's center
        // radius is the radius in pixels of the cirle to be drawn
        // paint contains the shader that will texture the shape
        canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter
                + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth - 4.0f,
                paintBorder);
        canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter
                + borderWidth, circleCenter - 4.0f, paint);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

    viewWidth = width - (borderWidth * 2);
    viewHeight = height - (borderWidth * 2);

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        // We were told how big to be
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        // Measure the text
        result = viewWidth;
    }

    return result;
}

private int measureHeight(int measureSpecHeight, int measureSpecWidth) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpecHeight);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpecHeight);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        // We were told how big to be
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        // Measure the text (beware: ascent is a negative number)
        result = viewHeight;
    }

    return (result + 2);
}}
```

And the xml file where I am using it is :-

```
<com.app.demo.customwidgets.CircularImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/userImage"
            android:src="@drawable/default_profile_pic"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />
```

Comment: same problem bhai , remove this line this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);

Comment: @Prannet Kumara, did you solve this issue ?

Comment: Yes! I used the "com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView" library to fix this issue.
Link : https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside `setup` method, call:

```
paintBorder.setAlpha(254);
```

Comment: Perfect answer! kudos (y) but alpha with 254 value indicates transparency or what?

Answer (score 3):

**you need try below code in lolipop.**

```
userImage.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Comment: It really works for me...thanks a lot!, you also can set this on the layout file