# How remove black background around the circular image view in android

Tags: android

I have created circular image view with the CircularImageView library

and I am facing issues with black background around the circular image in my layout, I tried to resolve this issue but I am failed to fix this issue

Following code is CircularImageView.java file

```
package de.hdodenhof.circleimageview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CircleImageView extends ImageView {

    private static final ScaleType SCALE_TYPE = ScaleType.CENTER_CROP;

    private static final Bitmap.Config BITMAP_CONFIG = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    private static final int COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION = 2;

    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 0;
    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;

    private final RectF mDrawableRect = new RectF();
    private final RectF mBorderRect = new RectF();

    private final Matrix mShaderMatrix = new Matrix();
    private final Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mBorderPaint = new Paint();

    private int mBorderColor = DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR;
    private int mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
    private int mBitmapWidth;
    private int mBitmapHeight;

    private float mDrawableRadius;
    private float mBorderRadius;

    private ColorFilter mColorFilter;

    private boolean mReady;
    private boolean mSetupPending;

    public CircleImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleImageView, defStyle, 0);

        mBorderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CircleImageView_border_width, DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH);
        mBorderColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_border_color, DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);

        a.recycle();

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        super.setScaleType(SCALE_TYPE);
        mReady = true;

        if (mSetupPending) {
            setup();
            mSetupPending = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ScaleType getScaleType() {
        return SCALE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
        if (scaleType != SCALE_TYPE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("ScaleType %s not supported.", scaleType));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdjustViewBounds(boolean adjustViewBounds) {
        if (adjustViewBounds) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("adjustViewBounds not supported.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (getDrawable() == null) {
            return;
        }

        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, mDrawableRadius, mBitmapPaint);
        if (mBorderWidth != 0) {
            canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, mBorderRadius, mBorderPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        setup();
    }

    public int getBorderColor() {
        return mBorderColor;
    }

    public void setBorderColor(int borderColor) {
        if (borderColor == mBorderColor) {
            return;
        }

        mBorderColor = borderColor;
        mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getBorderWidth() {
        return mBorderWidth;
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
        if (borderWidth == mBorderWidth) {
            return;
        }

        mBorderWidth = borderWidth;
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        mBitmap = bm;
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable);
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageResource(int resId) {
        super.setImageResource(resId);
        mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable());
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageURI(Uri uri) {
        super.setImageURI(uri);
        mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable());
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        if (cf == mColorFilter) {
            return;
        }

        mColorFilter = cf;
        mBitmapPaint.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);
        invalidate();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap;

            if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, BITMAP_CONFIG);
            } else {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), BITMAP_CONFIG);
            }

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            drawable.draw(canvas);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void setup() {
        if (!mReady) {
            mSetupPending = true;
            return;
        }

        if (mBitmap == null) {
            return;
        }

        mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(mBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBitmapPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

        mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
        mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);

        mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
        mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();

        mBorderRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        mBorderRadius = Math.min((mBorderRect.height() - mBorderWidth) / 2, (mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth) / 2);

        mDrawableRect.set(mBorderWidth, mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.height() - mBorderWidth);
        mDrawableRadius = Math.min(mDrawableRect.height() / 2, mDrawableRect.width() / 2);

        updateShaderMatrix();
        invalidate();
    }

    private void updateShaderMatrix() {
        float scale;
        float dx = 0;
        float dy = 0;

        mShaderMatrix.set(null);

        if (mBitmapWidth * mDrawableRect.height() > mDrawableRect.width() * mBitmapHeight) {
            scale = mDrawableRect.height() / (float) mBitmapHeight;
            dx = (mDrawableRect.width() - mBitmapWidth * scale) * 0.5f;
        } else {
            scale = mDrawableRect.width() / (float) mBitmapWidth;
            dy = (mDrawableRect.height() - mBitmapHeight * scale) * 0.5f;
        }

        mShaderMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        mShaderMatrix.postTranslate((int) (dx + 0.5f) + mBorderWidth, (int) (dy + 0.5f) + mBorderWidth);

        mBitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);
    }

}
```

And My layout is

```
<com.example.util.CircleImageView
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                app:border_color="@color/white"
                app:border_width="2dp" 
                android:id="@+id/chooseanavatar"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                 />
```

Comment: Already answered here.This may help you:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971251/black-background-in-circular-image-view-in-lollipop

Comment: I tried the solution ,that you have mentioned above, there is no change at all

Comment: mBorderPaint.setAlpha(254); I have used this solution but there is no change , what is setAlpla() ? do we need change the value according to our needs , is it a transparency

Answer (score 6):

I think I found a solution in lollipop.

```
myView = LinearLayout(parent layout for the circleview not the circleview itself)
myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

This disable hardware acceleration.

You can use this to circleimageview's parent view, profile_img_container.

Don't use this to circleimageview directly. It willl show you black outer circle.

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/profile_img_container"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:paddingTop="20dp"
  android:paddingBottom="20dp"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

          <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:id="@+id/profile_image"
             android:layout_width="96dp"
             android:layout_height="96dp"
             android:src="@drawable/profile002"
             android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
             app:civ_border_width="1dp"
             app:civ_border_color="#44000000"
             android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
             app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Source: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView/issues/31

Comment: please take note that on this line of code 
myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

myView = LinearLayout (parent layout for the circleview not the circleview itself).

Answer (score 4):

```
circle_imageview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

its working on me. [check this link](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView/issues/127)

Answer (score 1):

Came through the same problem *with a similar view* on 7.0.
Solved by drawing a white canvas before drawing anything else.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      canvas.drawARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
      ...
}
```

This workaround has the same visual result as setting a white background directly in the XML, *but will not work well if this view is child of a non-flat view (you will see a a white square)*.

Answer (score 1):

finally got solution ...
this problem resolve after enable hardwareAccelerated in android manifest file.
Add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to your manifest

After enable this no black area show behind the image while using shapeable image view.

hope your problem resolved ..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using lollipop currently because that problem only appears on lollipop devices,it works fine in pre-lollipop.

Try it with pre-lollipop and if you are using lollipop add this line:

paintBorder.setAlpha(254);

Comment: except lollipop , in all the versions,the image showing correctly without any black background . but we want target our app in the lollipop also. How can we resolve the issue ?

Comment: paintBorder.setAlpha(254); this gives a transperant background.

Comment: I tried the above line...but it's not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the background of RelativeLayout of CircleImageView. See below for reference:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="@dimen/base_padding"
        android:background="@color/light">

        <com.example.util.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/hugh"
            app:border_width="2dp"
            app:border_color="@color/dark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check this which says the samething as i said above: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView