# ShapeableImageView has black background out of rounded

Tags: android, android-studio

I have ShapeableImageView, and I set corner size. Applying rounded is successful but, In out of rounded It shows black background.

Can you tell me What's the problem?

I searched about it, someone say it's just preview. But It's showing when I run app too.

Like this. I wanna remove the black one.

[image]

My layout Xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        >
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnPinAddNewEventFolder"
                    android:layout_width="168dp"
                    android:layout_height="168dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/radius_add_pin_folder"
                    android:elevation="2dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/btn_add_pin_folder"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    />
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/clPinEventDefaultFolder"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    >
                    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                        android:id="@+id/pinEventDefaultFolderThumbnail"
                        android:layout_width="168dp"
                        android:layout_height="168dp"
                        android:src="@color/gray6"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundPinFolder"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        />
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ImgEventDefaultFolderNull"
                        android:layout_width="69dp"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_folder"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/gray5"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pinEventDefaultFolderThumbnail"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/pinEventDefaultFolderThumbnail"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pinEventDefaultFolderThumbnail"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pinEventDefaultFolderThumbnail" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDefaultEventPinFolder"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/nanumsquare_b"
                        android:text="이벤트 기본 폴더"
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvDefaultFolderPinNum"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pinEventDefaultFolderThumbnail"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pinEventDefaultFolderThumbnail"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvDefaultEventFolderPinNum"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/nanumsquare_b"
                        android:text="num"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/gray3"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/pinEventDefaultFolderThumbnail"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pinEventDefaultFolderThumbnail" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvEventPinFolder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

style code

```
<style name="RoundPinFolder">

    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">10%</item>
</style>
```

Comment: same issue , after use this i resolved this issue view visit .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72083107/12748481

Comment: Maybe try using dp instead of % for cornerSize

Answer (score 1):

Use padding inside `ShapeableImageView` like

`android:padding="0.5dp"`

Example

```
     <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imgBanner"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                              app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/roundedImageViewRounded"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                android:padding="0.5dp"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"                               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest file, in the **application** tag. set

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

By default it is **false**